# How can I retroactively create a link from a Jira issue to a Github pull request?

Tags: github, jira, pull-request, issue-tracking

My organisation's Jira has been setup to integrate with Github Enterprise. I know that I can establish a link to a Github PR that appears in the ["Development" panel of the Jira issue view](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-development-information-for-an-issue/) by including the Jira issue key in the PR title like so: `fix(BUG-123): ...` (as described [here](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/reference-issues-in-your-development-work/)).

However, if the PR title originally does not include the issue key and I add it by editing the PR title in order to establish the link retroactively it does not seem to get picked up by Jira. Am I missing something, is there some other way to establish the link explicitly, or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the integration handles later changes to PRs in this way. It would probably involve some kind of pulling all the PR data again to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Retroactively adding does work for me ; maybe just make sure :

1. To refresh your board
2. That your PR is not in draft state